# Adding search cum address bar in webview

Tags: android, webview

I want to add a text input box which should behave like google search cum address bar for a `webview` element. How this can be achieved ?

Comment: do you want to implement search cum address bar in webview? OR you want to implement Search cum Address bar using editText and show result in WebView?

Comment: I want to  implement Search cum Address bar using editText and show result in WebView